# How to add several graphs to a single tab using plotly express with python

Tags: python, plot, browser, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have a script that producing `5` different `graphs` that I want to present in one `web page`.
I use `python` with plotly express and define `pio.renderers.default = "browser"`.
The problem is that each graph is open in a new tab, and I want only one tab that I could share. 
My script contains two separate data frames:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

df1=pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

fig = px.bar(df1,x1, y1,color='a',barmode='group')
fig.show()   
fig = px.line(df2,x2, y2,color='b')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Could you post your code so we can understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I updated my question with an example for the script. my intention is that both graphs will be displayed in the same tab

Answer (score 5):

OK, you need to use `plotly.subplots.make_subplots`. I don't have your data, so I will use a simple data from `plotly` in the following code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig1 = px.bar(df, x='year', y='pop')
fig2 = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=False)
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

This will generate the following graph:
[image]

Side Note: `Plotly.express` shows figure in the browser by default, you don't have to specify it.

Comment: Glad I could help!